# VPN client for linux machine + support checkpoint gateway

Tags: linux, vpn

Since Checkpoint Company does not have a VPN client for Linux (checkpoint VPN SNX R71 is not fit for us because this VPN required changes on the gateway side ).

I'm trying to find if there is a VPN client (open source) or other VPN that can be installed on Linux machines and can connect to our Checkpoint gateway.

The following diagram described what we want (we need to install VPN clients on Linux machines (My Linux machine), so by that using this VPN client we can connect (via SSH)to the target Linux machine.

> My Linux machine     -->    fire wall (checkpoint NGR75)  -->  Checkpoint gateway (FW)  -->  target Linux machine

Please advice what are some alternatives?

Answer (score 3):

If you go to the CheckPoint website there's this page titled: [Remote Access (VPN) Clients](https://supportcenter.checkpoint.com/supportcenter/portal?os=Linux&productTab=downloads&product=175&eventSubmit_doShowproductpage=) which contains a list of appropriate VPN clients you can use with their products.

[image: ss #1]

Comment: do you mean to look on "Endpoint Security R73 .." ? I dont sure that VPN client , about SNX as I said in my question I cant use this because its required changes on checkpoint gateway side , I need to said that I get from the checkpoint this answer - checkpoint not have VPN clients for linux .

Comment: this is the answer that I get from checkpoint account service    --> " I am happy to assist you. At thist time Check Point does not offer a VPN solution for personal computers or laptops running the Linux operating system. I apologize for any inconvence that this may cause "

Comment: Late to the party. For those passing by, the snx 2012 is not officially supported but is till works. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/450229/getting-checkpoint-vpn-ssl-network-extender-working-in-command-line/453727%20snx